# Obtain learning curve of Gradient Boosted Tree model in PySpark

Tags: machine-learning, apache-spark, model-evaluations, pyspark

Currently there seems to be no method in PySpark of checkpointing the performance of a model at each gradient update. Is there a way to get the performance of a model at each gradient update so that a learning curve can be plotted?